# i am unable to scrape the phone number . Can anyone help me

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Here is the html content of that part.

```
<p class="contact-info " onclick="_ct('clntphn', 'lspg');">
  <i class="contactNo spriteImg"></i>
  <span><a><b>+(91)-80-30805680</b></a></span>
</p>
```

I have tried extracting this by:

```
soup.find('p',{'class':'contact-info'})
```

but in vain . It is unable to do the same.

Comment: Please post a sample of your html with the phone number.

Comment: What did command `soup.find` returned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `find` method with tag:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
s = soup(html_data, "lxml")
number = s.find('b').text
```

Output:

```
u'+(91)-80-30805680'
```

To get the first instance, you can try this:

```
new_s = s.findAll("p", {"class":"contact-info"})
new_data = [i.text for i in new_s]
print(new_data[0].replace("\n", ''))
```

Output:

```
+(91)-80-30805680
```

Comment: What will be if HTML has many `<b>` tag, this returned only first found tag

Comment: @Avinash glad to help!

Comment: @marni you can select which one you wanna care about first and then do that.

Answer (score 1):

You need to join you find methods into chain:

```
soup.find('p',{'class':'contact-info'}).find('b').text
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a CSS selector. As there is some whitespace around it, we can easily strip it.

```
soup.select_one('p.contact-info').get_text(strip=True)
```